# Eclipse doesn't resolve/autocomplete taglib of web fragment project

Tags: eclipse, jsf, taglib, composite-component, web-fragment

I've got a problem with eclipse (Kepler) from my Web Fragment project.
My taglib work well when I deactivate workspace resolution or when my component define into the "master" project.

My web fragment look like this:

```
`-- ComponentFragment
  `- src
    `- META-INF
      `- resources
       |-- composite-components
       |-- tags
       |-- faces-config.xml
       |-- MANIFEST.MF
       |-- component.taglib.xml
```

If eclipse have maven workspace resolution, component work well but i do not have completion from eclipse and if workspace resolution deactivate, component have a problem (EL expression contains `.` instead of `alphanumeric`, `-` or `_`) but completion work well.

I doesn't know how to resolve this and I need to have this webFragment project because he shared resources with multiple other project.

Did someone know how to configure this ?